# Digital Image Processing Contrast Stretching Histogram

Tags: image, image-processing, histogram, grayscale, contrast

Here I attach my code that I use to Draw the Histogram of the Contrasted image and also to convert a gray image into Contrast Image. Here I used low pint as 122 and highest point as 244. In the output histogram it reduce the height of the histogram.

I cannot find the error in my code

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Mat img = imread(argv[1], 1);

    if (!img.data) { 
        cout << "Could not find the image!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int height = img.rows;
    int width = img.cols;
    int widthstep = img.step;
    int ch = img.channels();

    printf("Height : %d\n", height);
    printf("Width : %d\n", width);
    printf("Widthstep : %d\n", widthstep);
    printf("No of channels : %d\n", ch);

    Mat gray_image(height, width, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));
    cvtColor(img, gray_image, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    Mat new_image = gray_image.clone();
    int v;
    int output{};

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            int v = (int)gray_image.at<uchar>(y, x);
            if (v >= 0 && v <= 122) {
                output = int((6 / 122) * v);
            }
            else if (v > 100 && v <= 244) {
                output = int(((244) / (122)) * (v - 122) + 6);
            }
            else if (v > 244 && v <= 255) {
                output = int(((5) / (11)) * (v - 244) + 250);
            }
            new_image.at<uchar>(y, x) = (uchar)output;
        }
    }

    int histn[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        histn[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            histn[(int)new_image.at<uchar>(y, x)] = histn[(int)new_image.at<uchar>(y, x)] + 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        cout << i << ":" << histn[i] << endl;
    }

    int hist_wn = 512;
    int hist_hn = 400;
    int bin_wn = cvRound((double)hist_wn / 256);

    Mat new_histogramImage(hist_hn, hist_wn, CV_8UC1, Scalar(255));

    int maxn = histn[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        if (maxn < histn[i]) {
            maxn = histn[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        histn[i] = ((double)histn[i] / maxn) * new_histogramImage.rows;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        line(new_histogramImage, Point(bin_wn * (i), hist_hn), Point(bin_wn * (i), hist_hn - histn[i]), Scalar(0), 1, 8, 0);
    }

    imwrite("Gray_Image.png", gray_image);
    imwrite("newcontrast_Image.png", new_image);
    imwrite("Histogram.png", new_histogramImage);

    namedWindow("Image");
    imshow("Image", img);
    namedWindow("Gray_Image");
    imshow("Gray_Image", gray_image);
    namedWindow("newcontrast_Image");
    imshow("newcontrast_Image", new_image);
    namedWindow("New_Histogram");
    imshow("New_Histogram", new_histogramImage);
    namedWindow("Old_Histogram");
    imshow("Old_Histogram", histImage);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the new and old histograms that I got as outputs
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for the question. Here I changed the lowest and highest point values as 100 and 240 and when using the values set those as decimals values.

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            int v = (int)gray_image.at<uchar>(y, x);
            if (v >= 0 && v <= 100) {
                output = int((5.0/ 100.0) * v);
            }
            else if (v > 100 && v <= 240) {
                output = int(((245.0) / (140.0)) * (v - 100.0) + 5.0);
            }
            else if (v > 240 && v <= 255) {
                output = int(((5.0) / (15.0)) * (v - 240.0) + 250.0);
            }
            new_image.at<uchar>(y, x) = (uchar)output;
        }
    }
```